# Add intercept column to a dataset

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I want to add a column of ones, interpreting as an intercept column to my current data frame. Any helpful comments would be appreciative.

Thanks!
Issac

Comment: You can simply use "cbind()", e.g.
d<-diag(9)
d<-cbind(rep(1,dim(d)[1]),d)

Comment: Welcome to the site Issac, check out the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). Based on the information in your question, you want to run some sort of regression analysis on your data. You do not need the intercept as a column in your data, you can include it directly in your model formula (e.g. `model <- lm(Y ~ 1 + X1)`, for a linear model with Y as a dependent variable and X1 as an independent, 1 is your intercept). If I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do, you can edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: the model I'm trying to fir is a multivariate linear mixed model with two responses and I wanted to examine the intercept-only fit with a random effect predictor to make a raw estimate of initial DIC value.

Answer (score 2):

Because of recycling, you just need `d$one <- 1` to make a column of ones with the name `one` in a data frame `d`.  But @AntoineVernet is exactly right that this is almost certainly unnecessary, even if you have a complex mixed model.

Try these models (which are admittedly simpler than yours) and examine the output to see what I mean.

```
set.seed(5)
d <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, 5), 
                y = round(rnorm(15, mean=10), 1), 
                g = factor(rep(1:5, each=3)) )
d$one <- 1

library(lme4)
lmer(y ~ x + (1|g), data=d)
lmer(y ~ (1|g), data=d)
lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|g), data=d)
lmer(y ~ 0 + one + (1|g), data=d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

incpt <- rep(1,nrows(df))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(incpt,df))